# Sci-fi b movie about a geek teenager who lives his life according to a fictional book

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

Shown in the UK on TV in the early 80s about a US geek teenager who is a social outcast and lives his entire life by a (fictional) book called (Corak?). Nothing to do with Tarzan.

This Corak is a space traveller, and long readings from his book intersperse the movie.
As an example the kid invents a gizmo that locks the reels of a fruit machine to a win position.

The book "Corak?" is the fantasy, and long passages are read throughout the film. In the end the kid dies and the book's traveller bemoans the emptiness of space.

Possibly a 60s/70's movie and American origin.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: Is the story-within-a-story the only thing about TV show that's fantastical?

Comment: Was the space traveller depicted visually? Or was it just parts of the book being read, maybe as a voiceover?

Comment: For those curious about why Tarzan would be called out, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korak_(character)

Comment: @Valorum If it is, would this be considered SF or F back in the 60's/70's?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Based on the description, I'd expect to see it categorised as "fantasy TV"